# Слова: обладание, бытие

Tags: значение-слов

У него было три сына.

Тут «было» в значении обладания или бытия? Обладать — это иметь что-то, как собственность, но *он* не может иметь *их* как собственность. А бытие — существовать.

Comment: "Было" в данном смысле обозначает время. Сравните: `у него три сына` (в настоящее время) или `у него есть три сына` и `у него было три сына` (когда-то в прошлом). "У него" выражает обладание.

Answer (score 1):

Традиционно в таких предложениях выделяется в качестве простого глагольного сказуемого глагол "быть", который здесь выступает как полнозначный глагол в экзистенциальном значении (значении существования). Относить этот глагол к числу связок в этом случае нет никаких оснований, так как он не приписывает подлежащему никакого признака.
Глагол "быть" может выступать в качестве полнозначного сказуемого. Например: "Вчера я был в театре".

Comment: Пример, который вы привели: "Вчера я был в театре". В нем был в значение существования тоже или нахождения?

Comment: Глагол быть имеет значение как существования, так и нахождения.В этом вы можете убедиться, если посмотрете в словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Ясно, что здесь семантически самостоятельный глагол

Значение слова Быть по Ефремовой:

1) иметься, существовать; 2) присутствовать // располагаться, размещаться где-л.; // разг. находиться на ком-л. (об одежде); 3) посещать кого-л., что-л.; // разг. прибывать (о транспорте); 4) происходить, совершаться, случаться; 5) разг. есть, имеется

У него было три сына - у него существовало(имелось) три сына . Так что обладание и существование здесь два в одном, недаром Ефремова даёт их в одном значении.